# Why a function that is $0$ in a neighborhood of a point must have a $0$ derivative at that point?

Tags: functions, derivatives, distribution-theory

The question was to show that $supp (D^{\alpha}f) \subset supp (f)$ if $f\in C_c^k(\Bbb R^n)$

My teacher's solution was, Let $x \in (supp f)^c \implies f(x)=0 \implies D^{\alpha}f(x)=0$ (since $(supp f)^c$ is open)

I didn't understand this last step, I mean even if $(supp f)^c$ is open, why does this fact give that $D^{\alpha}f(x)=0$ ??

N.B.: $supp f$ is the support of the function $f$

Maybe my question in other words is, if $f(a)=0$, what condition do we need so that we can deduce that $f'(a)=0$ ?

Comment: Please write an *informative* (not generic) title to help others find this question and its solution.  And who is "the doctor"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The topological support is closed by definition.

As the compliment of the support is open, there must exist an open neighborhood $U\ni x$ such that $f(y)=0$ for all $y\in U$. Thus all partial derivatives of $f$ must be $0$ at $x$, else the very definition of the derivative as the instantaneous rate of change would imply that $f$ must be non-zero somewhere in $U$. Think of the partial derivatives as forming the approximating plane for differentiable functions.

Comment: For example if $f(x)=0$ for all $x \in A$ and $A$ is a closed set different than $\{x\}$  why can't we deduce the same thing? Also you mean by the definition of the derivative $f'(a)=\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$? If you mean something else could you please add it?

Comment: Let $f(x)=x^2-1$. $f(1)=0$ and $f(-1)=0$, but the derivative is not $0$ at either of these points, even though $\{-1,1\}$ is a closed set. And yes I mean the standard definition of the derivative.

Answer (score 1):

The compactness of the support of $f$ is a sufficient condition for your implication.

Hint: Look at the definition of the first derivative as a limit.